# python beginner: try two things before exception?

Tags: python, combinations, try-except

I'm trying to write a script that accepts input for a number, and then checks to see

(a) that the input is in fact a number, and 
(b) that the number in question is less than or equal to 17.

I've tried a variety of "if" statements to no avail, and now I'm trying to wrap my head around "try" statements. This is my best attempt to date:

```
def listlength():
    print "How many things (up to 17) do you want in the list?"
    global listlong
    listlong = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        listlong = int(listlong)
        listlong <= 17
    except:
        print "Gotta be a number less than 17, chumpy!"
        listlength()
    liststretcher()
```

It works for the first element in the try: if it's not a numeral, I have to run through the listlength function again. But the second element (<=17) is completely ignored.

I've also tried

```
try:
    listlong = int(listlong) and listlong <= 17
```

...but that still gives me only a functional first check, and ignores the second entirely.

I also get the same result if I have two try statements:

```
    try:
        listlong = int(listlong)
    except:
        print "Gotta be a number, chumpy!"
        listlength()
    try: 
        listlong <=17
    except: 
        print "Gotta be less than 17!"
        listlength()
    liststretcher()
```

Is there a way to have try: check two things, and require both to pass before moving past the exception? Or do I have to make two different try: statements in the same definition before moving on to the liststretcher() command?

In response to S.Lott, below: my intention was that "try: listlong <=17" would check to see if the "listlong" variable was shorter than or equal to 17; if that check failed, it would then move to the "except"; if it passed, it would move on to liststretcher() below.

Reading the answers to date, I've got about eight things to follow up on...

Comment: [Don't use `except:`](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#except), rather be specific about which exceptions you want to catch.

Comment: What did you thing `listlong <= 17` was going to do?  Please **update** the question to explain what you think that statement does.  Please be **specific** on what that statement is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most of the answer:

```
def isIntLessThanSeventeen(listlong):
    try:
        listlong = int(listlong) # throws exception if not an int
        if listlong >= 17:
            raise ValueError
        return True
    except:
        return False

print isIntLessThanSeventeen(16) # True
print isIntLessThanSeventeen("abc") # False
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a if statement to check the relation, raising an exception manually if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing, and what S.Lott is trying to lead you to, is that the statement `listlong <= 17` does not raise an exception. It's just a conditional expression that yields either True or False, which value you then ignore.

What you mean to say, probably, is `assert( listlong <= 17 )`, which throws an AssertionError exception if its condition is False.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to fix your solution:

```
def listlength():
    print "How many things (up to 17) do you want in the list?"
    global listlong
    listlong = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        listlong = int(listlong)
        listlong <= 17
    except:
        print "Gotta be a number less than 17, chumpy!"
        listlength()
        return
    liststretcher()
```

The problem is that you're using a recursion when it's not needed, so try this:

```
def listlength():
    print "How many things (up to 17) do you want in the list?"
    global listlong
    listlong = raw_input("> ")
    value = None
    while value is None or and value > 17:
            try:
                listlong = int(listlong)
            except:
                print "Gotta be a number less than 17, chumpy!"
                value = None
    listlong = value
    liststretcher()
```

That way the function does not call itself and the call for *liststretcher* will happen only when the input was valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
length = ""
while not length.isdigit() or int(length) > 17:
   length = raw_input("Enter the length (max 17): ")
length = int(length)
```

Answer (score 0):

No reason to avoid recursion, this works as well:

```
def prompt_list_length(err=None):
    if err:
        print "ERROR: %s" % err
    print "How many things (up to 17) do you want in the list?"
    listlong = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        # See if the list can be converted to an integer,
        # Python will raise an excepton of type 'ValueError'
        # if it can't be converted.
        listlong = int(listlong)
    except ValueError:
        # Couldn't be converted to an integer.
        # Call the function recursively, include error message.
        listlong = prompt_list_length("The value provided wasn't an integer")
    except:
        # Catch any exception that isn't a ValueError... shouldn't hit this.
        # By simply telling it to 'raise', we're telling it to not handle
        # the exception and pass it along.
        raise
    if listlong > 17:
        # Again call it recursively.
        listlong = prompt_list_length("Gotta be a number less than 17, chumpy!")

    return listlong

input = prompt_list_length()
print "Final input value was: %d" % input
```